# Do Fitocracy points correlate to calories?

Tags: fitocracy

I told my personal trainer about Fitocracy and her first question was: do the points correlate to calories burned?

Obviously, quests do not, but what about if I log my workout without triggering a quest? Do those point values indicate how many calories I burned?

Answer (score 6):

No, points do not correlate with calories burned. In general, we believe the latter is a rather poor metric to rely on when it comes to fitness performance and progress.